# Identifying which Linux system library contains a function

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am using a dev system where I have to specify the lib name when accessing a function inside it.

I've used functions like open() before, and somehow found out that they're in libc.so.

Now I want to use lstat(), but it appears that this one is not in libc. Sadly, the man pages I looked at do not document the location of the functions.

So, two questions:

1. Can someone tell which lib hosts lstat?
2. How can I generally find this out? Other than using grep "name" on all files in the lib folder, I mean.

Comment: Can't you use the 'nm' command for this: `nm lib*.so* | grep lstat`. Untested hence the comment, not answer.

Comment: lstat is not present as a symbol in libc, it seems to be called __lxstat, and that is probably resolved at link time

Comment: Unfortunately, all I get from this is a long list of "nm: libXXX.sp.N: no symbols". Odd. Maybe something is damaged in my system.

Comment: nos - __lxstat is indeed there, but it does not appear to work - it keeps returning -1. I guess it's because it has more or different parameters.
(update)
Indeed - I should have checked the header file first. It's declared in there.

Comment: For dynamic objects, such as a shared library the `-D` option is needed with `nm` to display the dynamic symbols rather than the normal symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a simple testcase in C, compile it and run 'ldd -r' on it to check what libs are loaded. If you don't get lstat() in C then you have a problem on your dev env. Or this env dates back before the age of symlinks :-)

Comment: Good idea.
In this case the problem actually was that there is really no lstat in the lib, but only __lxstat. Which could be seen in the headers, though.

Comment: This idea is not too good if there is function from unknown and not-linked-in-by-default library. There will be no binary to run `ldd` on before library name is added to binary linking. PS: there is also `LD_DEBUG=all ./binary` to see actual linking process; ld.so will show what symbols are asked and where it try to find them.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it:

```
tomislav@malik:~$ cd /usr/lib
tomislav@malik:/usr/lib$ grep "lstat()" *
Binary file libperl.so.5.10 matches
Binary file libperl.so.5.10.0 matches
tomislav@malik:/usr/lib$
```

Comment: libperl? That can't be right. 
Use the 'nm' command instead. Such as `nm lib*.so* | grep lstat`.

Comment: Yes, the grep shows also _imports_, I believe, thus the wrong result about libperl.

Comment: libperl matches because it contains the string `lstat()`, which is a Perl function implemented here.  That has little to do with the underlying syscall.

Answer (score 1):

When I cross-compile Windows applications on Linux, if I have an issue with linking I tend to use this script that I named mingw-findin.   A similar script could be used for regular Linux compilation, just instead of using the mingw alternative, use regular nm and instead of looking in the cross-compile prefixed directory, look in /usr/lib.   To use this script, I run

./mingw-findin NameOfFunction

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
liblist=` ls /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib `

for i in $liblist
do

if x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/$i | grep -q $1; then
        echo $i
        x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/$i | grep $1
fi

done
```

Comment: Or `nm` with `-D` flag? On linux there are also /lib; so we should check /etc/ld.so.conf and /etc/ld.so.conf.d/* for search paths of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat ./foobar.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    struct stat buf;
    return lstat(".", &buf);
}


$ LD_DEBUG=bindings ./foobar 2>&1   | grep stat
31000:  binding file ./foobar [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: \
normal symbol `__lxstat' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Answer (score -2):

From the manpage (man lstat):

```
LSTAT(P)

NAME
       lstat - get symbolic link status

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/stat.h>

       int lstat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

Comment: OP wants to know what library the functions eventually get stored in, not what header file.

Answer (score -2):

`lstat` is in libc, and libc is linked in by default. You don't need to do anything to use `lstat` besides including the header file for it `#include <sys/stat.h>`

man pages usually state which library they are in.

Comment: I think I clearly pointed out that this is not about C but about a dev env where I need to specify the lib explicitly.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is in libc, so link to libc. If this is is some environment that has little to do with what's normally found on a linux machine you need to tell us what kind of environment this is.
There is no stock way to know where functions resides besides its documentation - which sometimes is lacking.

Comment: nos -- the only reason why I could not find it in libc was that it wasn't declared there, as you pointed out above. I've solved it now, thanks.