# How to find source library of a c++ static library function in linux?

Tags: c++, gdb, static-libraries

I have a C++ linux executable which is built using several static libraries, all with debug information 
How can I find the source library of a static library function which was called in the executable?

Comment: My old-school approach is to use nm on all the .a files and grep for the function name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326636/identifying-which-linux-system-library-contains-a-function

Comment: nm -A *.a | grep function_name