# How to determine in which .SO library is given C function?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries

I have this problem all the time in Linux programming. As long as all the manuals and almost all the source code for Linux are C-centric, all references to some function needs only some `include <something.h>` line and the function is accessible from the C/C++ code.

But I am programming in assembly language and know almost nothing about C/C++.

In order to be able to call some function, I have to import it from the corresponding .so library.

How to determine the file name of the library? It often differs from the name of the library itself and is not specified in the manuals.

For example, the name of the XLib is actually `libX11.so.6`. The name of the XShm extension library seems to be `libXext.so.6`.

Is there easy way to determine the secret real name of the library, using provided C manuals and references?

Comment: Why are you programming in assembly language? I would suggest to code in C and use `asm` chunks... Also, consider linking with `gcc`. Then you would be able to link `-lX11`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't like C/C++ languages syntax. Assembly is much more easy and readable for me. :) But not in Linux. :(

Comment: Then generate C code from some higher level language

Comment: Why do you ask? What are you coding in assembler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying which Linux system library contains a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326636/identifying-which-linux-system-library-contains-a-function)

Comment: Why so many assembly haters?... Respect to you @johnfound

Comment: @sashoalm - unfortunately, all the answers in this question are useless/not working. :(

Comment: @sashoalm - But the answer of Innocent Bystander is actually useful.

Comment: @sashoalm - My point is that I simply need **good** answer of my question.

Comment: You might want to note that C/C++ coders need to link to the appropriate libraries as well. This is distinct from including their respective headers...

Comment: @DevSolar - Is the name of the dynamic library specified in the C header files? If yes, it can be read from there and this is the exact answer to my question.

Comment: @johnfound: Short answer, no, it is not. (Since you aren't a C/C++ coder, I won't go into the long answer, which would have lots of dithering in it about you *could*... you get the idea.) C/C++ coders have the *exact same* problem: You need to check the docs of the libraries you're using, and sometimes you just have to grep it.

Comment: @sashoalm: The linked question **is** related, but **doesn't** provide a working answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a sure fire way, but it can help in many cases.

Basically, you can usually find the library name at the bottom of the `man` page.

Eg, `man XCreateWindow` says `libX11` on the last line. Then you look for `libX11.so` and use `nm` or `readelf` to see all exported functions.

Another example, `man XShm` says `libXext` at the bottom. And so on.

**UPDATE**

If the function is in section (2) of the man pages, it's a system call (see `man man`) and is provided by glibc, which would be `libc-2.??.so`.

Lastly (thanks Basile), if the function does not mention the library, it is also most likely provided by glibc.

DISCLAIMER: Again this is not a 100% accurate method -- but it should help in most cases.

Comment: Because `shmget` is in `libc` and man pages do not explicitly mention it

Answer (score 3):

This is another not-100%-accurate method that may give you some ideas as to how you can narrow things down a bit.  It doesn't *exactly* fit the question because it uses common linux utilities instead of man files, but it may still be helpful.

#### Use your distribution's package management software.

For example, on Arch Linux, if you were interested in a function in `GLFW/glfw3.h`, you could find out who owns that file:

```
$ pacman -Qo /usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
/usr/include/GLFW/glfw3.h is owned by glfw 3.1-1
```

Find out which `.so` files are in that package:

```
$ pacman -Ql glfw | grep 'so$'
glfw /usr/lib/libglfw.so
```

And, if needed, find the actual file that link points to:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/lib/libglfw.so
/usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.1
```

This will depend on your distribution.  I believe on Ubuntu/Debian you'd use `dpkg-query` instead.

---

**Edit:** DevSolar points out in a comment that you can use `apt-file search <header>` and `apt-file list <package>` instead of `dpkg-query -S <header>` and `dpkg-query -L <package>`.  `apt-file` appears to work even for packages that aren't installed (though it seems slower?).

I also noticed that (on my Ubuntu VM at least) that, e.g., *libglfw-dev* contains the `libglfw.so` symlink, while *libglfw2* contains the actual `libglfw.so.2` object.

---

Once you have a set of `.so` files, you can check them for whatever function you are interested in:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libglfw.so | grep "glfwCreateWindow"
0000000000007cd0 T glfwCreateWindow
```

Note that I pulled this last step from a comment on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326636/identifying-which-linux-system-library-contains-a-function) and don't fully understand it.  Maybe you could even skip the earlier steps and rely on `nm` and `grep` alone?

Comment: Well, I am using objdump instead of nm, but the idea is the same. It works actually, but to search all the .so files is very slow.

Comment: Yea maybe dump everything to a single text file, e.g. `nm -D /usr/lib/*.so > $HOME/sodb.txt` (or whatever is sane) and then search through that?

Comment: For Debian / Ubuntu / Mint you can use the `apt-file` tool. `apt-file search <header>` to find the package owning the file, and `apt-file list <package> | grep 'so$'` to list all .so files from the package.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you could use `gcc`  to link your program, and then it should be able to accept `-lX11` ; by using `gcc -v` instead of `gcc` you'll find out what is actually linked and how.

However, you have a much more significant issue than finding the `lib*.so.*`; most C or C++ APIs are described in header files, and these C or C++ header files also contain *symbolic* constants (like `O_RDONLY` for [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)...) or macros (like `WIFEXITED` in POSIX [wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) ...) whose value or expansion you should manually find in header files or documentations. (Quite often, such constants are either preprocessor `#define`-d constants or `enum` values). Also, some headers -in particular in C++- contains a lot of `inline`-d functions (or macros)!

A possible way might be to generate some C files to find all these constants, enums, macros, inlined functions..., and/or to customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) ...) to find them.

So my message is that for better or worse, the C language is *deeply* tied to Linux & POSIX.

You might restrict yourself to use only [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) from your assembler code. Then you won't use `libX11` and you don't need any header or constant (except the ones for syscalls, starting from `<asm/unistd.h>`).

BTW, in 2015, coding *entirely* in assembler for performance reasons is a mistake. The compiler is generating better code than you reasonably can (as soon as you have more than a few hundred machine instructions). In practice, you can code in assembler with GCC by using extended `asm` instructions in your C functions.

Or are you building your own compiler ? Then you should have told so in your question!

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) & the [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)

Comment: See, I don't use linker at all. FASM does not need it and generate directly the executable. And if I wanted to use C/C++ I wouldn't ask this question at all.

Comment: You can't avoid linkers to use shared libraries. At least, you need to code your own dynamic linker (replacing `ld.so`)

Comment: I am talking about static linking. The dynamic linking is part of the OS starting mechanism, not your program building process.

Comment: Your question mentions `libX11.so.6` not `libX11.a` so you want dynamic linking

Comment: Well, explain us how you are finding the numerical value of `O_RDONLY` or the expansion of `WIFEXITED` ... In other words, how do you can `open` or `wait` in your assembler code!

Comment: Yes, I want dynamic linking and I can do it in my programs. The only problem is that I can't find the name of the library that I need to link. The C references gives me the name of the function and the name of the C include .h file only.

Comment: The constants are easy - search google for O_RDONLY and you will find million pages where is given the numeric value of this constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `gcc` to tell you which file it would use for linking like so:

```
gcc --print-file-name=libX11.so
```

Sample output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
```

This file will usually be a symlink, so you'll have to pipe it through `readlink` or `realpath` to get the actual file. For example:

```
readlink -f $(gcc --print-file-name=libXext.so)
```

Sample output:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
```

Comment: Wrong, `--print-file-name` is for GCC internal files, not for external libraries!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `gcc`'s manpage does not mention any such restriction, and this does appear to work for all libraries.

Comment: @Wintermute Well, but how to know this "libX11.so" if I have only the function name for example `XCreateWindow`?

Comment: Ah. Hmm...I'd look into the documentation of `XCreateWindow`, to be honest. I suppose you could script a search for that, though. Along the lines of `find /usr/lib -name \*.so -exec nm -oD '{}' \; | grep ' T XCreateWindow'` -- although this particular bit could require some patience.